# Magento 2 API removes spaces within variables

Tags: api, response, magento2, whitespace

I am working with orders and invoices.
I noticed M2 (2.4.4) removes lots of spaces in almost all variables eg. for:

**order['billing_address']:**

```
'city': 'CHAMPIGNYSURMARNE'
```

In backend, it's well written 'CHAMPIGNY SUR MARNE'

Idem for :

**order['billing_address']**

```
'additional_information': [
            'Virementbancaire',
            'Votrecommandeseraexpédiéelorsquelevirementdesonmontantseraconfirméparnotreorganismebancaire.\r\nVoustrouvereznoscoordonnéesbancairesdanslaconfirmationdecommandeenvoyéesurvotreboîteemail.'
        ],
```

I also noticed that issue doesn't happen in all variables. Even if for the time, I can only see ONE value on witch it doesn't happen :

**order['status_histories']**

```
'comment': "Remboursement de 6,00\xa0€ hors ligne. <span style='color:deeppink'>(By Axel B)</span>",
```

Did anyone else ever noticed this ?

Answer (score 0):

My bad ! I post this answer because maybe, somebody one day could be as dizzy as me.
The reason is I use a new tool for formatting - among others - JSON and XML.
I recommend it to those who do not know it yet : **DevToys** (Mac an Win).
But it is responsible for my misfortunes because is't it that removes spaces when beautifying. As the file was long, I didn't even have a look a the row file. I've searched in the soft an option that could avoid this behaviour ... without success.